# Implicit commit in F4IF_INT_TABLE_VALUE_REQUEST popup?

Tags: commit, abap, dynpro, badi

I noticed that there is an implicit commit between the cycles mentioned above.

Now I am in an BADI, where I implement a method, which help states there should be no commits there. However, I have a requirement which is best to be implemented through this method.

And I use `F4IF_INT_TABLE_VALUE_REQUEST` module to allow user selection via popup.

Now I need to know whether this popup implicitly triggers the commit because there is also a PBO-PAI cycle involved. Is it?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Comment: The BADI documentation stated that there should be no commit? If so, I think giving a popup in that BADI is a bad idea and the it should be re-thinked. Is that really the good place to get values from the end-user? When is the BADI called?

Comment: It is our badi, from or module, implicit enhancements are not allowed in that project,  dirty assigns are a way, which is not completely forbidden, and some screen badi methods offer to do that. The architecture is very close to SAP standard. Before_save is the method,  guess, what the invoking bapi does after that badi jump in point...

Comment: Well, the solution depends on the requirement and the calling enviroment, which we don't know. Placing user interaction in a before_save( ) method seems to be a bit wrong.

Comment: I know,  I just wanted to clarify, whether popups issue that implicit commit. Ok, thanks a lot, i need to discuss that.

Comment: How did you *notice* that? Did you do DB trace? This sounds like nonsense. `F4IF_INT_TABLE_VALUE_REQUEST` restricts search help, it cannot do any commits to DB.

Comment: ? Sap Standard: Each PAI-PBO cycle commits.

Comment: @Suncatcher: I have PoC. I wrote a sample test program that called the FM with showing a popup. It commited implicitly.

Comment: I did that too, right now and tested that with various extra statements, and coworker, It is as stated / said / linked to by szako. The popup runs through the dialog step. In the debugging even BEFORE PAI is entered,  immediately after PBO my values, which I changed in the debugger, were already on the database. But, that was inside SE37. Anyway, thanks for proving/helping, szako.

Comment: @ Suncatcher: There is a famous german comedian, which has one major standard sentence....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I also stated in comments the short answer is yes.

`F4IF_INT_TABLE_VALUE_REQUEST` calls a popup window with CALL SCREEN and this command starts a new screen sequence ending another.

More (latest ABAP version) [here](http://help-legacy.sap.com/abapdocu_751/en/abendb_commit.htm), cited the exact case:

> **Completion of a dialog step**
>
> The program waits for a user action and does not occupy a work process
>   during this time. The next free work process is assigned to the
>   program in the next dialog step.